# impulse response values VAR statsmodels

Tags: python, vector-autoregression, statsmodels, impulse-response

I am trying to understand how the values of the irf plots are estimated

I read following page: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html
But I don't understand how the values of the impulse response are estimated.

I have a model that I fit with order of 3.

```
result = model.fit(3)
```

coefficients and residuals:

```
result.summary()
```

irf values:

```
result.irf(3).irfs
```

At first, I thought the values of the coefficients are equal to the values of the irfs, but that only holds for the first lagged value 'L1'.
After that, the values of the irfs start to differ.

An example:

Imagine there are three variables in the system: `GDP, Sales, Export`, with order `3`

**Coefficient for GDP -> Sales**

Results for equation Sales

```
L1.GDP = 1.37
L2.GDP = 1.63
L3.GDP = -0.69
```

**Impulse response for GDP -> Sales**

GDP -> Sales

```
irf(t1): 1.37
irf(t2): 1.31
irf(t3): -0.762
```

How do I obtain the values at `t2` and `t3`?

From the docs:

> Impulse responses are of interest in econometric studies: they are the estimated responses to a unit impulse in one of the variables. They are computed in practice using the MA representation of the VAR(p) process:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think values of IRFs should equal the coefficients? After all, the quoted text says they are computed using the MA representation, not the AR representation.

Comment: True, so I have a misconception - still trying to figure out how to calculate the values myself.. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps express the VAR as a VMA and then look for a relationship between the coefficients of the VMA and the IRFs?

Comment: The symbol  represents the moving average coefficient, what does Mu represent?
I'm really confused.

Comment: It is just the intercept. (It is a vector since $Y_t$ is multivariate.)